# Karate Http request add param conditionally

Tags: karate

Is there any way to add param conditionally?

I have the following request :

```
Given url "http://myURL"
And param time = time
When method DELETE
Then status  200
```

For example if time is 'undefined' or 'null' then completely ignore param time?

I know I can concatenate strings conditionally but I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `path` is designed so that a `null` value will be ignored. Also see `params`. I think that solves your problem.

EDIT: you can use `karate.get('variableName')` if you are dealing with variables that are `undefined` (although this is not recommended as it reduces maintainability of your tests).

```
* def time = karate.get('externalTime')
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I had to add this, because variable was undefined.
* def time = (typeof(externalTime) == 'undefined' ? null : externalTime)

Comment: @MiklosBalazsi there is a slightly better way: `* def time = karate.get('externalTime')`